# How to assign array into variable in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

The original and working array is this:

```
 var columns =[{
        name: 'level',
        minWidth: '200px'},
        {
        name: 'subject',
        minWidth: '70px'},
        {
        name: 'catid',
        minWidth: '70px'}],
```

However, I want to use if else statement to assign different array for different 'target' value.
So I tried as below but it doesn't seem to supply the array correctly to the 'columns' variable.

```
 var useThis=[];
        if(target=="subject")
        {
            useThis = {
            name: 'level',
            minWidth: '200px'},
            {
            name: 'subject',
            minWidth: '70px'},
            {
            name: 'catid',
            minWidth: '70px'};

        }
        else
        {
            useThis = {
            name: 'level',
            minWidth: '200px'};

        }
var columns="["+useThis+"],";
```

How do I assign array correctly with if else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var useThis=[];
        if(target=="subject")
        {
            useThis = [{  <---- Put here Opening bracket
            name: 'level',
            minWidth: '200px'},
            {
            name: 'subject',
            minWidth: '70px'},
            {
            name: 'catid',
            minWidth: '70px'}];  <--- Put here closing bracket

        }
        else
        {
            useThis = [{ <--- Put here opening bracket
            name: 'level',
            minWidth: '200px'}];  <--- Put here closing bracket

        }
var columns = useThis;
```

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovu3amyd/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the large brackets.

```
if(target=="subject")
        {
            useThis = [{
            name: 'level',
            minWidth: '200px'},
            {
            name: 'subject',
            minWidth: '70px'},
            {
            name: 'catid',
            minWidth: '70px'}];

        }
```

Here's how you'd use it,
http://jsfiddle.net/gvmy9r8o/

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the if-else statement itself. You have several problems in the rest of the code. You are assigning two different types of data (array of dictionaries or dictionary) depending on whether `if` or `else` is executed. Finally, you cannot just add string braces to your array when you assign `useThis` to `columns`.

```
var useThis=[];
    if(target=="subject")
    {
        useThis = [{
        name: 'level',
        minWidth: '200px'},
        {
        name: 'subject',
        minWidth: '70px'},
        {
        name: 'catid',
        minWidth: '70px'}];

    }
    else
    {
        useThis = [{
        name: 'level',
        minWidth: '200px'}];

    }
var columns = useThis;
```